# How to pass height of parent to child in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to pass parent's `width` to child widget in Flutter but I don't know how to pass it. Here I've two Widget to display in `Row` with half of the parent's width. Any help is appreciated please.

**Here is my code**

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    _cancelRequest(),
    _acceptRequest(),
  ],
)

Widget _cancelRequest() {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.0, horizontal: 20.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [AppColor.CARISSMA, AppColor.LIGHT_CORAL],
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
      child: Icon(
        Icons.close,
        color: AppColor.WHITE,
        size: 20,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _acceptRequest() {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.0, horizontal: 20.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [AppColor.THEME, AppColor.TURQUOISE_BLUE],
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
      child: Icon(
        Icons.check,
        color: AppColor.WHITE,
        size: 20,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you can do this. You can check here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints. Basically - parent passes the constraints to its child; child returns its size back to the parent. Not the other way around. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html

Comment: You can wrap both the children in an 'Expanded' widget and it will distribute half the width to both the children. But make sure that the 'Row' doesn't have unbounded width.